# How to fix my text to pdf conversion?

Tags: c#, itext

I used this code for saving my TextBox content to PDF but it only support for English. It doesn't support for Sinhala, Tamil, Braille letters.

```
<sfd.Title = "Save As PDF";

        sfd.Filter = "(*.pdf)|*.pdf";

        sfd.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";

        if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            iTextSharp.text.Document doc = new iTextSharp.text.Document();

            iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(sfd.FileName, FileMode.Create));

            doc.Open();

            doc.Add(new iTextSharp.text.Paragraph(textBox1.Text));

            doc.Close();

         }>
```

Can you please help me to fix it.

[image]

This is Sinhala text it does not support for this code please help

Comment: Maybe a font problem? There should be iTextSharp command to set the font to use in the PDF - you must use a font that has the characters for Sinhala, Tamil etc.

Comment: Sound like a font-problem. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727765/itextsharp-international-text for example.

Comment: I used font for sinhala textbox but yet not display sinhala text how can i do? :(

Comment: please give me another code you have similar to this

Comment: If you know clear code for this text box converted jpg then jpg converted into pdf please send me .................................can you please help me @ MiMo & @Furqan Safdar