# Doddle Report iTextSharp Turkish Characters

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

I am using codeplex [doddlereport](https://doddlereport.codeplex.com/) project to report my linq queries. It's simple and very successful. But there is only one problem for me. When i report to excel , html or csv files turkish characters seems ok. But when i try to export my queries to pdf with doddlereport.itextsharp turkish characters hidden. Hidden characters are ("İ,ı,Ş,ş,Ğ,ğ,Ö,ö,ç,Ç,ü,Ü"). Anyone uses doddlereport and export to pdf with turkish characters help me how do i success?

Or how can i change doddlereport font family for pdf files? Can be solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `ConvertStyleToFont` method of https://doddlereport.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/DoddleReport.iTextSharp/PdfReportWriter.cs file to support Identity_H encoding (Unicode encoding). [More info here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727765/itextsharp-international-text/1729278#1729278)

```
using DoddleReport;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using Font = iTextSharp.text.Font;

namespace Test
{
    public class PdfReportWriter // …
    {
        public static Font ConvertStyleToFont(ReportStyle reportStyle, string fontFamily)
        {
            var style = Font.NORMAL;
            if (reportStyle.Underline)
            {
                style = Font.UNDERLINE;
            }
            else if (reportStyle.Bold || reportStyle.Italic)
            {
                if (reportStyle.Bold && reportStyle.Italic)
                {
                    style = Font.BOLDITALIC;
                }
                else if (reportStyle.Bold)
                {
                    style = Font.BOLD;
                }
                else
                {
                    style = Font.ITALIC;
                }
            }

            // todo: to use this method you need to register your fonts at the beginning of the report
            // FontFactory.Register(@"c:\windows\fonts\myfont.ttf");

            return FontFactory.GetFont(
                fontFamily, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED,
                reportStyle.FontSize, style,
                new BaseColor(reportStyle.ForeColor.R, reportStyle.ForeColor.G, reportStyle.ForeColor.B));
        }
    }
}
```

Or you can try http://pdfreport.codeplex.com

Comment: Added the modified method.