# iTextSharp displaying greek chars

Tags: c#, itext, non-ascii-characters

I'm trying to display the sigma char into a PDF generated by code in my `C#` (`Framework 4`) application. I'm using `iTextSharp` (V. 4.1.2.0).

Whenever I try and print my char using the following snippet...

```
string l_sTmpText = "\u03A3";
l_table.AddCell(new Phrase(l_sTmpText, MyFont));
```

...I get nothing but a blank space in my PDF. When going in debug, My sigma char is properly display within Visual Studio so I suspect this is an encoding problem.

I've found and read this post : [iTextSharp international text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727765/itextsharp-international-text/1729278#1729278)...

...But I still cannot manage to make it work. I tried to create a `BaseFont` like this :

```
private static BaseFont MySpecialBaseFont = iTextSharp.text.pdf.BaseFont.CreateFont("C:\Windows\Fonts\Arial.ttf", iTextSharp.text.pdf.BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, iTextSharp.text.pdf.BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
```

My problem is the construction of a `Phrase` object requires a `Font` and not a `BaseFont`. I'm stuck around here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found my mistake... The beginning was right :

```
private static BaseFont MySpecialBaseFont = iTextSharp.text.pdf.BaseFont.CreateFont("C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\Arial.ttf", iTextSharp.text.pdf.BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, iTextSharp.text.pdf.BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
```

I then had to create a font (I was stuck there) from my BaseFont :

```
private static Font MySpecialCharfont = new iTextSharp.text.Font(MySpecialBaseFont);
```

I can then create my Phrase object :

```
new Phrase(l_sTabulationString + l_sTmpText.ToLowerInvariant(), MySpecialCharfont)
```

Please note the ToLowerInvariant() that allowed me to get a lowerCase version of the sigma char. Hope this will help someone else...