# itextsharp not showing hindi fonts correctly

Tags: unicode, itext

We have created PDF using itext sharp in which we are display hindi text, but in pdf some text is coming correctly whereas some text is not showing in correct way. any help?

we are expecting to show hindi text in correct format

Comment: Please share the code sample with which you have created the file. If you used some specific font(file), add that too. More information is better

Comment: I have use simple PDF generation code from itextsharp. I have not use any specific font as hindi text is coming but the problem is text is not coming in correct format

Comment: iTextSharp does not support Hindi at all.

Answer (score 2):

iTextSharp does not support Hindi at all. What you can do is add a Hindi Font that you can find online maually to your setup. this is described here: [International text in iTextSharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727765/itextsharp-international-text)